# check if the XML element has xsi:nil="true"

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have an element `<ABC xsi:nil="true">`. I want  to write a condition in dataweave 2.0 to check the value of this xsi:nil and if it is equal to "true" I want to transform as `"ABC": null` in JSON, I am using skipNullOn="everywhere" in the script. I tried using `payload.ABC.@nil == "true"` but it is giving `null`

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
fun replaceElementAndAttribute(value:Any, name: String, newValue: Any) = do {
    value match {
        case obj is Object -> obj mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
            if(key.@nil  ~= "true")
                (key): "null"
            else    
                (key) @((replaceElementAndAttribute(key.@, name, newValue))): replaceElementAndAttribute(value, name, newValue)
        )
        else -> value
    }
}   
---
replaceElementAndAttribute(payload,"", "")
```

This is similar to what's being mentioned [here](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Replace-or-mask-the-value-of-a-xml-element-and-attribute-using-data-weave-2-0).

However with this recursive function its going to output the value as "null" string..